# "sich verständigen" oder "zu verstehen geben"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Ist *zu verstehen geben* weit verbreitet in deutschsprachigen Ländern heutzutage?

Welcher Situationen *zu verstehen geben* passt?

Auch, könntet ihr mir bitte mit irgendwelcher Beilpiele versorgen?

Comment: Entschuldigung, ich wohne in Russland. Russische Sprachäquivalente nicht immer ähneln derjenigen von dem Deutsch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sich verständigen`

means to communicate (with each other).

> Konntest du dich mit ihnen verständigen? *(Could you understand each other?)*

`jemandem zu verstehen geben`

means to make someone understand (slight negative connotation).

> Wir müssen ihnen zu verstehen geben, dass mit uns nicht zu spaßen ist. *(We have to make them understand that one doesn't screw around with us.)*
>
> Ich dachte, ich gab dir zu verstehen, dass du das nicht machen darfst. *(I thought I made it clear,, that you're not allowed to do that.)*